# How to put a subtitle label under textlabel in cell?

Tags: swift

I have a tableView, which I have put 2 text labels (I need 3 when I'm done). 
Both labels shows up, but my issue is that the `detailTextLabel` is inline with the `titlelabel` which it obviously shouldn't be.

I have tried to add dynamic sizing to the rows because I thought that the height of the cells was what constrained the detailtext label to fit on a line below `titlelabel`. 
That was not the case though.

This is what I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    if myCell == nil {
       myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
       myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    }
    let item: Parsexml = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! Parsexml
    myCell?.textLabel!.text = item.name! + " | " + item.address!
    myCell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Category:" + item.city!
    myCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
    myCell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
    myCell?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 8)
    myCell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.3)

    return myCell!
}
```

How do I force my `detailtextlabel` to sit below my `titlelabel`?

Comment: Ahmad, why do you downvote my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the first assignment inside the following `IF` is useless because it is overwritten by the next assignment.

```
if myCell == nil {
    myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)
}
```

By the way, you nee to use the `.subtitle` style, not `.value2`.

So replace this

```
if myCell == nil {
    myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)
}
```

with this

```
if myCell == nil {
    myCell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
}
```

### Removing the optional

Even better you can make myCell a non optional value

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    let item: Parsexml = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! Parsexml
    myCell.textLabel!.text = item.name! + " | " + item.address!
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Category:" + item.city!
    myCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
    myCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 8)
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.3)

    return myCell
}
```

Comment: Great! That solved it. -Thanks alot! 
But what if i want to have a 3rd row ?

Comment: Then you need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` with 3 `UILabel`s